# I have created tab using elementskit plugin and its woking like on hover ,i want to open page when its click

Tags: jquery, wordpress, tabs, elementor

[please check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xb0wI.png)

I have created tab using elementskit plugin and its working like on hover ,I want to open page when its click .I want to open custom page when click on tab but when it hover its open their existent content.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.